# How to solve index out of range error in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
from sys import stdin

def arrayRotateCheck(arr, n):
    i=1
    
    while arr[i]>arr[i-1] and i<n-1:
        i+=1      
    if i==n-1:
        return 0
    else:
        return i

#Taking Input Using Fast I/O
def takeInput() :
    n = int(stdin.readline().rstrip())
    if n == 0:
        return list(), 0

    arr = list(map(int, stdin.readline().rstrip().split(" ")))
    return arr, n


#main
t = int(stdin.readline().rstrip())

while t > 0 :

    arr, n = takeInput()
    print(arrayRotateCheck(arr, n))

    t -= 1
```

This is a Python code finding array rotation index, the following line causing index out of range error. How to overcome this error.

```
while arr[i]>arr[i-1] and i<n-1:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to add a condition in `arrayRotateCheck` function, when the length of array is 1 then what will be the output of your program.

then here is code

```
def arrayRotateCheck(arr, n):
    i = 1
    if len(arr) == 1:
        return 0

    while arr[i] > arr[i - 1] and i < n - 1:
        i += 1
    if i == n - 1:
        return 0
    else:
        return i
```

Answer (score 0):

Your test is backwards, so the second half of it doesn't save you the way it should:

```
while arr[i]>arr[i-1] and i<n-1:
```

is reading from and testing `arr[i]` before it's actually validated that `i` is less than `n - 1`. If you flip the test components so it doesn't read from `arr` until it's validated the index (and the inputs from the user aren't lies and `n` is never zero; as is, it's kind of a silly design, because `n` is the user's *asserted* number of inputs, but `arr`'s length doesn't have to agree with that in any way), you won't go out of bounds:

```
while i < n-1 and arr[i] > arr[i-1]:
```

That short-circuits and doesn't even test `arr[i] > arr[i-1]` when `i` is greater than or equal to `n - 1`, exiting the loop immediately.

As a side-note, if you're accepting input a line at a time from the user, you don't need an `import` to gain access to `sys.stdin`, and you can simplify the code significantly, replacing each use of:

```
stdin.readline().rstrip()
```

with just:

```
input()
```

where [`input` reads precisely one line from stdin, and strips the newline for you](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input). I'd also recommend calling `.split()` instead of `.split(" ")`; the latter will misbehave if the user accidentally includes additional spaces between elements, or uses tabs, or includes a leading space. The former will ignore all leading and trailing whitespace, and split on *runs* of any type of whitespace, so   `1    2   3` will produce the same result as `1 2 3`.

Comment: Is `input()` as fast, though? (They're intentionally doing it their way for speed, after all.)

Comment: @KellyBundy: I guess `#Taking Input Using Fast I/O` *might* mean that choice was intentional; `input()` is a bit slower (given the work it does to ensure existing output data is flushed before prompting). The whole design is kinda screwball though; there's no reason to accept `n` in the first place AFAICT (I'm assuming it's some weird requirement for a coding challenge that wasn't written specifically for Python), so I figured I'd mention the simplification available if *maximum* performance isn't important (especially if the input really is being typed by a user live).

Comment: Yes, most certainly a coding challenge with input suitable for multiple languages. I've seen input() vs stdin make the difference between TimeLimitExceeded and Accepted, though I don't remember the details.